# How can I scrape multiple pages of a website, eacg page having href of type "javascript:get_next_page()"?

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to **scrape** data from the educationworld.in website to get a table of name, address and ratings of all the school.

I utilized Python and Beautiful Soup4 to extract my data. I have reached as far to extract the data and import it into a CSV but I am now having a problem of scraping data from multiple pages of the website. I want to extract ALL THE SCHOOLS but my script is limited only to one page. I want to loop it in away that it will capture all data from all pages found in the site.

Attached below is my script. I need help on creating code that will capture ALL data from the website and not just one site but multiple.

```
    import requests

    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

    for i in range(0,21): 

        if i%5==0:

            url='http://www.educationworld.in/institute%2Fsearch%2Fdata%2Fsrch%5Bid_city%5D%3D388%26srch%5Bhmsrchcity%5D%3DFaridabad+%28Haryana%29%26srch%5Bcourse%5D%3D39%26srch%5Bhomepg%5D%3D1/pgn/1','{}','5','institute_searchInstitutes'.format(i)

            response = requests.get(url)
            html = response.content

            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
            print soup.title

            listing = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class': 'srch_box_bg mrgn_btm5 pdng3 p_bgcl'})
            for rec in listing:
                name =  rec.find('div', attrs = {'class': ' fltlft'}).a.text
                ratings = rec.find('div', attrs = {'class': 'fltlft mrgn_rht5'}).text
                address = rec.find('div', attrs = {'class': 'lnhit_20 wrd_wrp'}).text
                print name, "\t", ratings, "\t", address 
                print "\n"'
```

I want 0,5,10 in place of {}... to get link of page 1,2 ,3... of the websie.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is an HTML parser, not a JavaScript-compatible browser substitute. I would recommend using something like phantomjs for this.

Comment: it's going to be a lot easier to just write a few userscripts to extract what you need.

Comment: I am a beginner. Can you show how phantomjs will help me to solve my problem. @Hamms

Comment: Can u show me via example @dandavis ?